# How to call javascript from Jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call jquery function in side of java script. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function calljs(){
      getUserMail(usermMail);
      }

  $(function() {
      function getUserMail(usermMail) {
       ***some code*****
      }
  });
</script>
```

I got error from browser console:

> ReferenceError: getUserMail is not defined.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: For `calljs` function, there's no `getUserMail` function to access.

Comment: it cannot call a function within another function, from another function.

Comment: If possible for call jquery function from java script.

Comment: You can call Jquery yes.  Why are you trying to attach this function to Jquery?  You basically have your function in an unnamed closure, thereby making it so you cannot access it.

Comment: I am using Google api for get email so i want to pass gmail id from java script function to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really compulsory to put the function with in the jquery's ready callback (which I don't think is compulsory) use the following way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var getUserMail = null;
   function calljs(){
      if ( null !== getUserMail ) {
          getUserMail(usermMail);
      }
   }

  $(function() {
      getUserMail = function (usermMail) {
       ***some code*****
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understand, the method is not defined when the method is being called. So define it before it is getting called

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function getUserMail(usermMail) {
       ***some code*****
   }

   function calljs(){
      getUserMail(usermMail);
      }

  $(function() {
      // 
  });
</script>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do ,

```
 $(document).ready(function(event) {
            getUserMail(usermMail);
        });
```

and define it like ,

```
function getUserMail(usermMail){
. . .
}
```

or using jquery ,

```
$(document).on('click', ".selector", function);
```

trigger a function on an event

Answer (score 0):

`getUserMail` is not defined in a [scope](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/) that is accessible to `calljs`.  This is why you get the `ReferenceError`; in the context in which you tried to invoke `getUserMail` there was no function with that name available.

```
   // At this point nothing is defined
   function calljs(){
      getUserMail(usermMail);
   }
   // now calljs is defined as a global and can be invoked from anywhere


  $(function() { // this line is calling a function named $ (an alias for jQuery)
                 // and passing it an anonymous function as a parameter.
      function getUserMail(usermMail) { // This function is being defined inside
                                        // the scope of the anonymous function,
                                        // it can be used anywhere inside the 
                                        // anonymous function but not outside it.
       // ***some code*****
      }
  });
  // we are now outside the scope of the anonymous function,
  // getUserMail is no longer in our scope and can't be called from here.
```

The easiest and likely best solution for most situations would be to make sure that any functions that call each other are in the same scope.

From what I can tell you don't really need `calljs`, you were just trying to use it to poke a hole into the scope of the anonymous function where `getUserMail` is defined.

Instead you should probably get rid of `calljs` and move any code that is calling `getUserMail` inside the `ready` callback. If `getUserMail` needs to wait for the `ready` callback to be fired before you call it, any code that invokes it also should be inside the `ready` callback too. (Things like event handlers that call it should already be inside the `ready` callback anyway.)

If there is a reason that you can't move it into the `ready` callback, such as something in another .js file needs to be able to call it etc, your application might be too complicated to be realistically maintained as [jQuery soup](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/01/keeping-jquery-in-check.html). It might be worth the effort to port it to a framework such as [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) or [Angular](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fangularjs.org%2F).

Also so you know, there is [no need to use the `type` attribute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=936s) on your `script` tags. JavaScript is the only language that has wide support in the browser and all browsers default to using JavaScript for `script` tags.